# How Change Url Path for Jekyll Blog on a GitHub Subdirectory?

Tags: github, jekyll, blogs

Good day,

I wrote a site builder. Source here : https://github.com/koy-odasi/core

and

I installed my site (https://github.com/barak-framework/blog) in subdirectory using https://github.com/koy-odasi/core

Subdirectory has a branch `gh-pages` and deployed here : https://barak-framework.github.io/blog/

But i have a problem. [pager](https://github.com/koy-odasi/core/blob/master/_/_layouts/post.html#L65) works incorrectly
So `page.previous.url` and `page.next.url` url paths have not **blog** subdirectory:

- https://barak-framework.github.io/categories/linux/lamp/

but `page.previous.url` and `page.next.url` url paths should be in like this:

- https://barak-framework.github.io/blog/categories/linux/lamp/

My Jekyll configuration file here : https://github.com/barak-framework/blog/blob/gh-pages/_/_config.yml

Can you help me?

Best regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/354577).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trt adding this to your _config.yml: `baseurl: "/blog"` and possibly add `{{ site.baseurl }}` to your links in templates

Comment: Thank you, i updated my site with **baseurl:  `/blog`**
But problem not solved.
`page.previous.url` and `page.next.url` not incorrectly

Comment: i changed `{{ page.previous.url }}` to `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.previous.url }}` and worked. thank you.